# Android fade in not working

Tags: java, android, animation, fadein, alpha

android newb here. I got fade out animations to work but not fade in animations. What is wrong with it? This method is called after a fade out method. The way the fade out works is by fading the view out and then making it gone. Doing the opposite in my fadeInLogin method seems not to work. Also I call fadeInLogin with a delay after the fadeOut so I don't think that these animations are interfering with each other although it is possible.

```
 view1.animate()
            .alpha(0f)//Fades buttons
            .setDuration(5000)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    view1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            });
```

Here is my code.

```
public void fadeInLogin() {


    view1 = findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    view1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   view1.animate()
            .alpha(1f)
            .setDuration(2000)
            .setListener(null);

    view2 = findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
    view2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    view2.animate()
            .alpha(1f)
            .setDuration(2000)
            .setListener(null).start();
    view3 = findViewById(R.id.editText);

    view3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    view3.animate()
            .alpha(1f)
            .setDuration(2000)
            .setListener(null).start();
    view4 = findViewById(R.id.loginTextView);

    view4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    view4.animate()
            .alpha(1f)
            .setDuration(2000)
            .setListener(null).start();
    view5 = findViewById(R.id.ipText);

    view5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    view5.animate()
            .alpha(1f)
            .setDuration(2000)
            .setListener(null).start();


            }
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
 view1 = findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
 view1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 view1.setAlpha(0);
 view1.animate()
        .alpha(1f)
        .setDuration(2000)
        .setListener(null);
```

Comment: This did not work either... it was also the code I had earlier...? Anything else I can try?

Comment: But I have just test it and it works for me, sorry no idea:-(

Comment: Oh well. Thanks for helping though

Comment: yes, I did, I changed it and it still did not work, I got it though. I was not fading them in at the right time in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call `start` on the view1 animation.