# Fade in not working but fade out Animation works on Android

Tags: android, animation

I use this method to show any view that need a **fade in** or a **fade out** `Animation`.

It works perfectly when I pass **false** to execute the fade out animation but when I pass **true**, the fade in doesn't execute, instead, It just appears after *500ms* without animation;

```
private void setViewTransition(final boolean isVisible, final View view) {

    Animation fadeAnim;

    if (isVisible) {
        fadeAnim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        if (view.getAlpha() == 1.0f) {
            return;
        }
    } else {
        fadeAnim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
        if (view.getAlpha() == 0.0f) {
            return;
        }
    }

    fadeAnim.setDuration(500);
    fadeAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            if (isVisible) {
                view.setAlpha(1.0f);
            } else {
                view.setAlpha(0.0f);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });

    view.startAnimation(fadeAnim);
}
```

It might be related to that issue: [Android fade in not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758840/android-fade-in-not-working) which never got any answers...

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try with changing alpha to 0.0f from 1.0f in onAnimationEnd() function and vice versa.

Comment: didn't work... :( Its just made everything appears at the wrong time...

Comment: Change every value with another, that is all 1.0 with 0.0 and 0.0 with 1.0. because 1.0 alpha means visible and you used for invisible.

Comment: Same behaviour, the fade out works and not the fade-in... But now the items is there when it shouldn't be...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I'm not entirely sure why your way doesn't work. It is a bit roundabout and is probably more complicated than it needs to be to get a fade animation. Here's a really concise way of doing it instead (for API 12+).

```
private void setViewTransition(boolean isVisible, View view) {
    view.animate().alpha(isVisible ? 1.0f : 0.0f).setDuration(500);
}
```

Comment: Wow, very neat solution! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks